# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, sqlplus

I am  creating a package and after that I am doing a prompt to create a trigger on a table which will check old values and new values:

```
set serveroutput on
set LIN 200
set feedback off
set verify off
set embedded on
set heading off
spool tmp.sql

prompt create or replace trigger aud_&1
prompt after update on &1
prompt for each row
prompt begin

select '    audit_pkg.check_val( ''&1'', ''' || column_name ||          ''', ' || ':new.' || column_name || ', :old.' ||             column_name || ');'
from user_tab_columns where table_name = upper('&1') 
/
prompt end;
prompt /

spool off
set feedback on
set embedded off
set heading on
set verify on

@tmp
-------------
```

But when I run the script it always compiles with an error:

[image: This is the error]

All it means is that it misses out the `;` after end:

[image: The problem]

So my question is what do I need to add to my script to include the required `;` and yes of course I have tried a few things myself such as adding `;;` on line 95 but nothing works.

Comment: do you need add ; at the `line 93` ?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried but this did not fix the problem.

Comment: you need remove `/` at the 94 line bcz sqlplus run your statement when find the simbol and add `;` at line 93... then `line 92` - the `;` at the end of query is not correct... finally.. can you put the query as a text... it would be easy to check syntax

Comment: Check your script for unbalanced () BEGIN-END IF-THEN-ELSIF-END LOOP-END LOOP etc.

Comment: are- i did the things you mentioned removing / from line 94 and added ; on then end of 93, but removing the ; from the end of the query causes other errors, so i left that in there however this still has not fixed the problem. I have added the script as text now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceed analogously to the generation of the plsql calls inside your script.
Instead of

```
prompt end;
```

write

```
select 'end;' from dual
/
```